# How to have an appropriately sized text within image?

Tags: graphics, photoshop

Let's say I have an image dimensions of which are X-by-Y.
I am going to import it into LaTeX document and make its width 8.6 centimeters. 
How should I make sure that the text on my image looks similar to default 12 pt in the final document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a programming question but anyway:

1. Open the [Image > Image Size](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7945a.html) dialog, uncheck the "resample" checkbox (to make sure the pixel dimensions of the image is not modified),  and set the width of your image to be 8.6 cm.
2. When you add text, set the font size to be 12 pt.